# React, conditional rendering wont register change in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The `if` statement in `canBookSlot()` is only checked once for some reason. The second time `canBookSlot()` is triggered, the `userDetailsObj.canBook` should be `0` after running `updateUser()`. And according to the console log it is the case, but the `if` statement still runs, why?

```
let userDetailsString = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
let userDetailsObj = JSON.parse(userDetailsString);

const updateUser = () => {
  userDetailsObj["hasBooked"] = 1;
  userDetailsObj["canBook"] = 0;
};

const canBookSlot = (id) => {
  if (userDetailsObj.canBook != 0) { // always true
    updateUser();
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/book/week1/ex", {
      room: userDetailsObj.room,
      id: id.id + 1,
    }).then(() => updateData());
  } else {
    console.log("already booked");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each render `userDetailsObj` will take that value from `localStorage`. That's how every variable inside a component which isn't a `state` made with `useState` hook, or a `ref` made with `useRef` hook behaves. You can fix your problem this by using a `state`, like so:

```
const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDetails")));
const updateUser = () => {
  const newUserDetails = { ...userDetailsObj, hasBooked: 1, canBook: 0 };
  setUserDetails(newUserDetails);
  localStorage.setItem("userDetails", JSON.stringify(newUserDetails));
};

const canBookSlot = (id) => {
  if (userDetails.canBook != 0) {
    //Always true
    updateUser();
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/book/week1/ex", {
      room: userDetailsObj.room,
      id: id.id + 1,
    }).then(() => updateData());
  } else {
    console.log("already booked");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify where this code runs? Are you using a class component or functional component? Would you mind sharing the entire component? If it is doing what I think it is doing, the `let userDetailsString = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");` is running *every render* which means on every render, it grabs the value in localStorage and uses that, rather than using your object stored in `userDetailsObj`.

If you are using functional components, you could fix this by using state.

```
  let userDetailsString = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
  let [userDetailsObj, updateUserDetailObj] = useState(JSON.parse(userDetailsString));

  const updateUser = () => {
    let u = { ...userDetailsObj, 
    hasBooked: 1,
    canBook: 0,
    }
    updateUserDetailObj(u);
  };
```

If you are using class Components, let me know and I'll update it with that option.

Comment: Sorry, looks like @yousoumar beat me too it.